# Extbase (TYPO3 9.5) n:m relation with timestamp

Tags: timestamp, typo3, extbase, typo3-9.x

I'm just building an extension that has Users and Messages tables. The Message object has a n:m relation "readByUser" so that I can see which users have read which messages. That works fine, but I also want to see when the messages have been read. Unfortunately Extbase doesn't provide this out of the box (there's no tstamp field in the nm table).
I thought about using a MySQL TIMESTAMP field but don't know how to access this from the Model / Repository.
Does anyone has an idea how to solve this?

Thanks
Seb

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would solve this by creating my own custom MM table, which means you'll have 3 models: `User`, `ReadMessage`, `Message`. `ReadMessage` is the custom MM table and has 3 properties: `user`, `message` and `tstamp`.